# nginx wss proxy doesn`t work

Tags: nginx, proxy, wss

I`m trying to run wss reverse proxy with nginx, but when i`m trying to connect, i`m getting error without any error codes. When i turned off ssl websocket started working correctly.
My nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 8082 ssl;
        ssl_certificate <certificate>;
        ssl_certificate_key <certificate_key>;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:24444/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Comment: offtopic due lacking in research. moreover using Google shows a nice [example](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)